# Destructor call in a comma-separated expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, object-lifetime, temporary-objects, comma-operator

consider the following example program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct t
{
    ~t() {cout << "destroyed\n"; }
};
int main()
{
    cout << "test\n";
    t(), cout << "doing stuff\n";
    cout << "end\n";
}
```

The output I get with GCC 4.9.2 is:

```
test 
doing stuff 
destroyed 
end
```

cpp.sh link: http://cpp.sh/3cvm

However according to cppreference about the comma operator:

> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded, and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins

I'd expect `~t()` to be called before `cout << "doing stuff"`

Is this a standard behavior? If so, where is it defined in the standard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Its result is discarded" means that the subexpression's *value* (here of type `t`) is ignored.

Its lifetime, however, is unaffected: as any all temporaries, it is destructed at the end of the full-expression (i.e. the semicolon here).

Answer (score 6):

The cppreference wording here is unfortunate.

As with any temporary, this one will last until the end of the *full-expression* in which it appears.

By "side effects" it is talking about the *construction* of the temporary.

Comment: Basically it's just a copy of the standard wording (with a little adjustment).

Comment: cppreference clarified

Comment: Is a temporary's construction formally a side-effect?

Comment: @Quentin: Anything observable that the construction causes, is a side effect. To be honest, I'm a little surprised that the same doesn't apply to destruction.